# Netlogo Profiler: How can the exclusive time be greater than the inclusive time?

Tags: netlogo, profiler

I am trying to optimize my NetLogo model using the Profiler extension. I get the following output [excerpt]:

```
Profiler
BEGIN PROFILING DUMP
Sorted by Exclusive Time
Name                               Calls Incl T(ms) Excl T(ms) Excl/calls
COMPLETE-COOKING                   38741      0.711   4480.369      0.116
GET-RECIPE                         10701   2618.651   2618.651      0.245
GET-EQUIPMENT                      38741   1204.293   1204.293      0.031
SELECT-RECIPE-AT-TICK                990   9533.460    470.269      0.475
GIVE-RECIPE-REVIEW                 10701      4.294    449.523      0.042
```

`COMPLETE-COOKING` and `GIVE-RECIPE-REVIEW` have a greater exclusive than inclusive time.

How can this be? And if it is an error, how do I fix it?

Comment: I never used this extension but got curious from your question, so I made a small toy model and I am getting some unexpected output too (or at least some output that I fail to understand). This includes exclusive time being sometimes greater than inclusive time, but also procedures appearing more than once in the report and with different times measured. I read [in the description page](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/profiler.html) that it is still considered experimental, so there might be some weird behaviour...

Comment: Hi Matteo,
So you assume that the problem is with the profiler-extension itself rather than the code of ours models. That leads me to the question if there is any other way to track the performance of single procedures in a  model?

I can only think of the timer-extension. However, this will require changes to the code and will impact performance.

Comment: If you believe the profiler extension is malfunctioning, consider reporting the problem to the NetLogo development team, via GitHub or  by writing bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu.

Comment: Chris, that is my feeling but I am not practical with this extension, so rather than an assumption of the extension being the problem take it as a mini extra piece of experience that goes in the same direction as yours. Unfortunately I'm not aware of another option that you can use