# How to use a command all the 4th item nested lists in netlogo

Tags: list, netlogo, mean, nested-lists

I have built a long nested list having the following profile:
`set my-list [A 1 2 3 4] [B 5 6 7 8] [C 9 10 11 12]`

I'd like to apply the `mean`command to the fourth item of each nested lists, so in the example to
**4 8 12**

but without building a list in loop that would look like `[4 8 12]` (to save computing time).

Is it possible ?

using `let comp mean (item i item 4 (my-list))` or `let comp mean (item 4 (my-list))` aren't obviously working.

The answer would be useful to other part of the model that I'm building.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have concerns about speed, so I wonder, does the model actually run slow? How long are your lists? Have you used the profiler extension to measure the model and determine bottlenecks? 
If speed is a problem, then perhaps a long list of lists is is not the best structure to use. Perhaps the data in item 4 should be kept in its own list from the beginning, so it doesn’t need to be extracted. Perhaps instead of a list of lists of (different) data, you might use a breed of turtles, with 5 variables, so you can do “sum [ var4 ] of dataturtles “

Comment: Hello, I answer here about your comment below as well. My question was asked with a small reproducible example. I'm still building a larger model that will involve a world of 4000 x 4000 patches, no turtles, and multiple procedures. So far, for this specific procedures, the list would have a length of +/- 16000 list of 4 items.  I'm just testing my model on smaller dataset now and will run the bigger version on a super computer. The list is built from a calculation with temporary patches properties (vary at each tick) using all patches that share one property (Owner).

Comment: The resulting value should only be allocated to Patch of the same Owner but only with an extra "true" property (only one patch getting the value from multiple patches). I worked with a list of list to make it simplier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`map`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) primitive is very well suited for these sorts of calculations with lists. It allows you to perform a reporter separately for each part of a list and then returns the results as a new list.

```
let test-list [1 2 3]
show map [x -> x + 1] test-list
;> [2 3 4]
```

In your case, you would use map to cycle through your list of lists, and use the `item` primitive to extract the necessary number from each sublist (`map [x -> item 4 x ] my-list`). This then returns them as a list of which you can take the mean.

```
to check-mean-2
  
  let my-list [["a" 1 2 3 4] ["b" 5 6 7 8] ["c" 9 10 11 12]]
  
  let my-mean mean map [x -> item 4 x ] my-list

  print my-mean

end
```

EDIT: Although mine looks more efficient on first glance, Matteo's version actually runs quicker (at least on my machine)

```
globals [my-list]

to setup
  
  set my-list [["a" 1 2 3 4] ["b" 5 6 7 8] ["c" 9 10 11 12]]
  
end

to check-mean
  
  let timer-list []
  
  repeat 10 [
    
    reset-timer
    
    repeat 1000000 [
      
      let the-sum 0
      
      let i 0
      while [i < length my-list] [
        set the-sum (the-sum + item 4 (item i my-list))
        set i i + 1
      ]
      let my-mean the-sum / i
    ]
    
    
    
    let the-timer timer ; ~0.207
    show the-timer
    set timer-list lput the-timer timer-list 
    
  ]
  
  show word "mean: " (mean timer-list) ; 0.210
  
  
end

to check-mean-2
    
  let timer-list []
  
  repeat 10 [
    
    reset-timer
    
    repeat 1000000 [
      let my-mean mean map [x -> item 4 x ] my-list
    ]
    
    let the-timer timer
    show the-timer
    set timer-list lput the-timer timer-list 
    
  ]
  
  show word "mean: " (mean timer-list) ; 0.235
  
end
```

ANOTHER EDIT: Finally two more versions using reduce instead of map. Version 3 is the fastest of them all but you should take notice of the fact that my-list has a 0 added to it in this version. This might make is slightly less conveniet for other purposes. You can also add this 0 to it during the calculation as seen in version 4, but that drives up the time again.

```
to check-mean-3
    
  set my-list [0 ["a" 1 2 3 4] ["b" 5 6 7 8] ["c" 9 10 11 12]]
  
  
  let timer-list []
  
  repeat 10 [
    
    reset-timer
    
    repeat 1000000 [
      
      let my-sum reduce [ [x y] -> x + item 4 y] my-list
      
      let my-mean my-sum / (length my-list - 1)
  
    ]
    
    let the-timer timer
    show the-timer
    set timer-list lput the-timer timer-list 
    
  ]
  
  show word "mean: " (mean timer-list) ; 0.170
  
end

to check-mean-4
    
  set my-list [["a" 1 2 3 4] ["b" 5 6 7 8] ["c" 9 10 11 12]]
  
  
  let timer-list []
  
  repeat 10 [
    
    reset-timer
    
    repeat 1000000 [
      
      let my-new-list fput 0 my-list
      
      let my-sum reduce [ [x y] -> x + item 4 y] my-new-list
      
      let my-mean my-sum / (length my-list - 1)
  
    ]
    
    let the-timer timer
    show the-timer
    set timer-list lput the-timer timer-list 
    
  ]
  
  show word "mean: " (mean timer-list) ; 0.226
  
end
```

Comment: Ahah, saw your update just after commenting (under my answer) that your approach looked more efficient. @Sarahdata - moral of the story: you have two viable options, up to you now to consider if you want to test them further for speed and/or if this scale of difference is relevant for you in the end and/or if you want to consider other aspects for your choice (i.e. concise syntax etc)

Comment: The inefficiency in my version probably comes from map creating a new list. I tried another way that does not create a new list but instead uses reduce to work with a variable as you did. It is faster but does require the initial list to be slightly altered, which in and of itself can drive up the time again

Comment: Makes sense! Which suggests that Sara's intention not to handle any further lists was spot on

Comment: LeirsW, adding an item to the front (or back)  is a list is pretty darn fast because of the way NetLogo stores lists. Adding a 0 to a list of lists so you can use reduce on it is Classic NetLogo Style, and even appears in some models in the library, so good on you!  I

Comment: worry that these ad-how tests may not be testing the actual use case. Like, 4 item list 1 million times, vis a 1000 item list  4000 times. OP said is was a long list. The 4 item example is not sufficient for speed  testing.  In deed, if it is only 4 items and always 4 items, maybe unrolling the loop would be faster. But would it matter? How many turtles or patches are involved?  Only using something like the profiler would reveal the true bottlenecks.

Comment: @TurtleZero That is a very good criticism. I can imagine that the longer the list of list becomes, the more efficient it becomes to add the 0 to the front and use reduce.

Comment: Thank you @LeirsW ! I although don't understand `let my-new-list fput 0 my-list`. Why adding a 0 ?

Comment: @Sarahdata, adding the zero gives the ```REDUCE``` command a starting place for the SUM operation. See, `REDUCE` starts by doing "A operation B" for the first two items in the list., Then that result is the new A, the next item is the new B, and it repeats (A operation B). So, its like `SET A A + ITEM 4 B` , if A was a list, that would not make any sense. So we add a 0 to the front of the list. That 0 is the first A... so that (SET A A + item 4 B) makes sense.. We're adding a place for the sum to accumulate.

Answer (score 2):

First things first: did you mean to say that such nested list is built such as the one below?

```
set my-list [[A 1 2 3 4] [B 5 6 7 8] [C 9 10 11 12]]
```

Note the extra pair of square brackets, that make this actually a list of lists. Even if that was the case, NetLogo wouldn't let you use that syntax:

- Either because A, B and C are lacking quotation marks if you intend them to be strings;
- Or because, if A, B and C are variables, NetLogo expects literal values (we can get around this problem by using `(list ...)` instead of `[]`).

In the first case, it would have to be:

```
set my-list [["a" 1 2 3 4] ["b" 5 6 7 8] ["c" 9 10 11 12]]
```

In the second case, it would have to be:

```
set my-list (list (list a 1 2 3 4) (list b 5 6 7 8) (list c 9 10 11 12))
```

All of the above just to make sure we are all on the same page (in general, please make sure that the code you post in your question is valid for the language you are asking about. As you can see, it would save a lot of time and space!).

Anyway I imagine that what you come up with is something of this type:

```
[["a" 1 2 3 4] ["b" 5 6 7 8] ["c" 9 10 11 12]]
```

I would use a `while` loop to iterate through the inner lists. You can create a local variable to keep track of the sum of the numbers you extract as you iterate through the inner lists, and then divide that sum by the number of times you extracted a number:

```
to check-mean
  let my-list [["a" 1 2 3 4] ["b" 5 6 7 8] ["c" 9 10 11 12]]
  
  let the-sum 0
  
  let i 0
  while [i < length my-list] [
    set the-sum (the-sum + item 4 (item i my-list))
    set i i + 1
  ]
  
  print the-sum / i
end
```

Comment: Hi Matteo, thanks for your answer. Indeed, I meant that list: `[["a" 1 2 3 4] ["b" 5 6 7 8] ["c" 9 10 11 12]]` . I just wrote that it has the "profile" `[A 1 2 3 4]` (string than numerics). Your point is however well noted. Your answer propose to compute a new variable in a loop (which is easier than building a list in a loop to which we apply the command) but my question was more like "is it possible to apply a the mean command to specific items of nested lists without using a loop"

Comment: or in another word : "what is the less computational-demanding procedure to apply a command to specific item of nested lists" ? For example, beside the mean, I also would like to calculate the standard deviation of the 4th item of the nested lists

Comment: @Sarahdata See LeirsW's excellent answer. I think the point is that, in a way or another, you have to either create a new list or use some kind of loop, or both. What `map` does there is a (probably more efficient) version of using a `while` loop throughout the length of the list. It returns a new list (`map [x -> item 4 x] my-list` is in fact a list) but I don't think it can get any better than that. At a first glance, I might prefer LeirsW's approach with `map`

Comment: @Sarahdata If you really need to squeeze any little drop of efficiency out of your code, consider checking the [profiler extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/profiler.html#:~:text=Using%20the%20Profiler%20Extension,to%20focus%20your%20speedup%20efforts.), but also be aware that it might give some [dodgy results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69198920/netlogo-profiler-how-can-the-exclusive-time-be-greater-than-the-inclusive-time)

Answer (score 0):

From the answers above and adding a step in the procedure (mean and sd for groups of items having the same "region" in the list), here-below is my final code using `map` as the mean and sd are already calculated in a `while-loop`. Moreover, I assumed that calculating manually the standard deviation would create even more lists of list and complicate the code.

```
to create-successor-list
   
  set successor-list map [inner-list -> (list inner-list 0 0 ) ] region-data
  let i 0
  while [i < length region-data] [
    let current-item item i region-data
      set temp-profitability-list (filter [current-inner-list -> (item 1 current-inner-list = current-item)] profitability-list )
      set prof-mean mean map [x -> item 4 x ] temp-profitability-list
      set prof-sd standard-deviation map  [x -> item 4 x ] temp-profitability-list
      set successor-list replace-item i successor-list (replace-item 1 item i successor-list (prof-mean))
      set successor-list replace-item i successor-list (replace-item 2 item i successor-list (prof-sd))
      set i i + 1
      set temp-profitability-list [ ]
  ]    
end
```